# Calculus Compress Spring

Tags: calculus, physics

I have a question I cannot seem to get correct and am looking for some help.

Suppose a force of $40~\text{N}$ is required to compress a spring $3~\text{cm}$ from its equilibrium length. How much force is required to compress this an additional $5~\text{cm}$. (Recall $W = \int F dx$ and $F = kx$.)

What I did so far is
\begin{align*}
F & =kx\\
40 & =k(x)\\
W & = \int_{3}^{8} \frac{40x}{x} dx\\
W & = 320-120 = 200N
\end{align*}

I know this isn't the correct answer and I cannot figure out how to do it.
Thank you!

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Also, note that you have not used the fact that $40~\text{N}$ of force is required to compress the spring $3~\text{cm}$ from its equilibrium length.  You need that fact to determine $k$.

Comment: Also, note that work is measured in Joules (J) rather than Newtons (N).  In terms of Newtons and meters (m), $\text{J} = \text{N} \cdot \text{m}$.

Comment: Work is pretty much irrelevant to this specific question, so that part of the hint doesn’t make much sense unless there’s more to this problem later. Taussig’s comment about units is spot on, too. You’re looking for force in Newtons, so computing a value measured in Joules is perhaps not the right approach.

Comment: So I got that k = 40/3. What do I do with this?

Comment: substitute for $k$ and find $W$ via definition integration (what are the bounds of that integral)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason we are told that $40~\text{N}$ of force is required to compress the spring $3~\text{cm}$ is that this allows us to solve for $k$.

We need to consider the units.  Since a Newton ($\text{N}$) is a unit of force and $F = ma$, where $m$ is the mass and $a$ is the acceleration,
$$\text{N} = \text{kg} \cdot \frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}^2}$$
where $\text{kg}$ stands for kilograms, $\text{m}$ stands for meters, and $\text{s}$ stands for seconds.  Hence, we need to express $3~\text{cm}$ as $0.03~\text{m}$.

Using the equation $F = kx$ for the force applied to the spring to compress it $x~\text{m}$ gives 
$$k = \frac{F}{x} = \frac{40~\text{N}}{0.03~\text{m}} = \frac{4000}{3}~\frac{\text{N}}{\text{m}}$$
Hence, the force applied to the spring to compress it $x~\text{m}$ as a function of $x$ is 
$$F(x) = \left(\frac{4000}{3}~\frac{\text{N}}{\text{m}}\right)x$$
To determine the additional force needed to compress the spring from $3~\text{cm} = 0.03~\text{m}$ to $8~\text{cm} = 0.08~\text{m}$, you need to compute $F(0.08~\text{m}) - F(0.03~\text{m})$.

Comment: I realized after writing the answer that if you express both $k$ and $x$ in terms of centimeters, you will obtain the same result.  If you do that, $$k = \frac{40}{3}~\frac{\text{N}}{\text{cm}}$$ and you need to compute $F(8~\text{cm}) - F(3~\text{cm})$.

Comment: So with this, the answer would come to an additional .666N/cm needed?

Comment: That is incorrect.  \begin{align*} F(8~\text{cm}) - F(3~\text{cm}) & = \left(\frac{40}{3}~\frac{\text{N}}{\text{cm}}\right)(8~\text{cm}) - \left(\frac{40}{3}~\frac{\text{N}}{\text{cm}}\right)(3~\text{cm})\\ & = \left(\frac{40}{3}~\frac{\text{N}}{\text{cm}}\right)(8~\text{cm} - 3~\text{cm})\\ & = \left(\frac{40}{3}~\frac{\text{N}}{\text{cm}}\right)(5~\text{cm})\\ & = \frac{200}{3}~\text{N} \end{align*}

Comment: Ahh yes, I forgot to change the parameter to cm from m. Thanks a ton!